# Completion Handlers in Swift

Tags: swift, closures, completionhandler

I'm fairly new at swift development and trying to get a handle on closures and completion handlers. I have a function with the following declaration inside a struct called ObjectData

```
func getData(id1:Int, id2:Int, completion: (dataObject? -> Void))
```

I am trying to call this function like

```
ObjectData.getData(1, id2: 2){
    (let myObject) in
}
```

but i get the following error

> Cannot invoke 'getData' with an argument list of type '(NSNumber, id2:
>   NSNumber, (_) -> _)'

Please can someone help

Comment: Is `dataObject` a type in here `(dataObject? -> Void)` ?

Comment: yes dataObject is another struct, i dont know why it doest show as the light blue color @nkukushkin

Comment: It does not show because it does not start with capital (I am guessing). You should always name your objects starting with capital letter, CamelCase :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For better readability, change the header to this. Remember that you have to declare types, not variable names:

```
func getData(id1:Int, id2:Int, completion: (ObjectData?) -> (Void))
```

Now I personally use this syntax to use closures:

```
self.getData(1, id2: 1) { (data) -> (Void) in

     // Some code executed in closure
}
```

If you want to study further, you can find full [syntax of closures](http://fuckingclosuresyntax.com/) here (notice appropriate name of the website).
Hope it helps!

Comment: hi Jiri, in my code dataObject is a data type. Thats why i am confused iv done something similar to this elsewhere and it worked.

Comment: nope that didn't work ... everything code wise looks ok ... but t just doesn't want to work :(.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? can you provide more code, and what exactly did not work so I can help you? Either update the question, or post more code on https://gist.github.com/

Comment: This was right ... rookie mistake on my behalf ... my syntax was right !! the issue was in my function declaration i had Int, but in my function call i was passing through NSNumber. Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

Far away from my Mac now, so I can't test, but try this:

```
ObjectData.getData(1, id2: 2, (dataObject) -> { 
...code...
});
```

Also can't check now, but I think this also should work:

```
    ObjectData.getData(1, id2: 2)(dataObject){ 
...code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize your class first (ex. var objectData = ObjectData()) , and then call function with objectData.getData... it should work that way ..

Answer (score 0):

In SWIFT 3,It is known as completion closure.

```
func getData(id1:Int, id2:Int, completion:@escaping(dataObject?) -> (Void)) {

    //Do the stuff before calling completion closure
    completion(value as? dataObject)   
}

ObjectData.getData(id1:1, id2: 2,completion:{(data) -> (Void) in
    //Do the completion stuff here
}
```